# No module named 'celery.tasks' when trying to import inspect/revoke function in celery

Tags: python, django, import, celery, importerror

I was trying to import revoke() method from celery module as follows -

```
from celery.tasks.control import revoke
```

but it says, "No module named 'celery.tasks'". Why is it so? All celery tasks are working perfectly fine but whenever I try to revoke/inspect a particular celery task using it's ID, this returns error.

Is there any other way to revoke/inspect a celery task using it's ID?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling it from wrong celery module. You have to use the `Celery` object's revoke method as follows.

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery(__name__)

# or
from celery import current_app as app

app.control.revoke(task_ids)
```

You can also use revoke function of the AsyncResult returned as follows:

```
async_result = add.delay(2,3)
async_result.revoke()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with AsyncResult and it worked for me.